# Error while Handling 404 error for Spring Boot REST application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-4

I trying my hand out in Spring boot exception handling . 
I have created a REST application and the application works for all valid url. 
I am trying to handle the exceptions for invalid url.
But if i try hitting the application with an invalid url , i am getting the below exception:-

```
13:04:02.940 [http-bio-8081-exec-3] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 44 ms
13:04:03.177 [http-bio-8081-exec-3] ERROR o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for/sample/processgetMessage5 (response is committed), so this response may have the wrong status code
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:348) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) [spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:104) [spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:89) [spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
```

Being new to spring boot I am not able to figure out the reason. Any pointers or suggestion will be helpful.

Wanted to try out the options mentioned in this site[enter link description here](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc), once i am able to remove the exception.

Any pointers on how to handle 404 with annotations in spring 4 will be very helpful.

Trying out the below code :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
.......

  @Bean
            public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

                return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

                    ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/401.html");
                    ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/401.html");
                    ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/401.html");

                    container.addErrorPages(error401Page, error404Page, error500Page);
                }
            };
        }
```

Adding the dependency from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>            
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>            
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

PFB the updated stack trace:-

```
22:09:03.210 [http-bio-8081-exec-3] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 28 ms
22:09:03.413 [http-bio-8081-exec-3] ERROR o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Cannot forward to error page for/applicationurl/processMessage11 (response is committed), so this response may have the wrong status code
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:348) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:134) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:58) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:87) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:100) [spring-boot-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar:1.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:7.0.55
```

]

The application works fine for valid url mapping. It is build using spring boot. PFB the app annotated classes:-

```
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class AppConfig {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(AppConfig .class, args);
        }



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

public class WebApplicationXML extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }   

}
```

Comment: It works for me with a simple 404. Maybe it's time to share the whole project and some steps to reproduce?

Comment: I got something to work, though not completely. After removing @EnableWebMvc, i am not getting the error. I am getting forwared to the default Whitemarker page.

Comment: You need to open up a bit. Is there a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the mapping to redirect to custom html pages if a 404 happens. PFB the changes done for this:

- Removed the Annotation @EnableWebMvc from the
  WebConfig.java class. This is done to remove the error “response
  already committed”, on trying any invalid url.
- Add the below code in WebConfig.java class and the revenant html pages:

  ```
  @Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

      return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
          @Override
          public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

              ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                      "/401.html");
              ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                      "/404.html");
              ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(
                      HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500.html");
              ErrorPage error505Page = new ErrorPage(
                      HttpStatus.HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED, "/505.html");
              ErrorPage error506Page = new ErrorPage(
                      HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, "/405.html");
              container.addErrorPages(error401Page, error404Page,
                      error500Page, error505Page, error506Page);
          }
      };
  }
  ```

Thanks a lot for the suggestions ans hep. It was very useful.

I followed this link after getting through the initial exeception

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below blog to handle mvc exception handling

http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I am not able to follow the steps in the link, as i get the error mentioned above when I try an unknown URL.

Comment: I have given the the same link in the question itself as my reference. If any info on the exception, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Spring Boot 1.1.5.RELEASE.

Comment: Using The latest version

Comment: Thanks Dave Syer for the suggestion. Using the latest version of spring boot.I have added the spring boot dependency from pom.xml.But no luck...Same error

Comment: The stack trace still says 1.1.4. Can you update that as well if you didn't already?

Comment: Yes Dave, I forgot to update the stack trace. I have added it now.