# Spring Boot handle 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I'm struggling with the error handling in spring, specially with the 404 error.

I have a `ExceptionController` with the `ControllerAdvice` annotation, with this i handle the 403 error, like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
public String handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return "403";
}
```

But i'm not able to handle 404 the same way.

I have read about to create an own DispatcherServlet and set ThrowExceptionIfNohandlerFound to true. But this doesn't work for me

Source: [HOWTO handle 404 exceptions globally using Spring MVC configured using Java based Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24498662/1809221) , https://stackoverflow.com/a/27224123/1809221 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973476/1809221

After this i found a nice and clean solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25805387/1809221

But with this i doesn't get my custome 404 i get a blank white page.

Any ideas?

Thank's in advance

Comment: What did you try to handle the 404?

Comment: i tried all the suggested solutions there posted in the links

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30193013/5856415)

Comment: Thanks! That's works like a charm. Can you post it, then i can accept this as the answer.

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Comment: I have [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47384824/3077218) to a very similar issue. Check it out. Hope that helps.